# How to write a trigger which deletes a product category when the last product in the productcategory is deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger which should delete a product category when the last product in that product category is deleted. But it should only work when deleting ONE product and not more than one.

I have written the trigger, but the problem is that it deletes a product category when the product category is empty, and it does not matter if one or more products are deleted at a time.

Here is my code so far:

```
drop trigger if exists mytrigger1
go

create trigger mytrigger1
on Product
after delete
as
    select count(*) 
    from DELETED 
    having count(*) = 1

begin
    delete from Productcategory 
    where Produktcategory.produktcategory_id in 
          (select productcategory_id 
           from Productcategory
           left join Product on Product.product_productcategory_id = Produktcategory.produktcategory_id
           where product_productcategory_id is null) 
end
go
```

Comment: So if I delete the last two products in a category you don't want to delete the category? Why? Seems an arbitrary way to sometimes leave an empty category and sometimes not...

Comment: You don't appear to be referencing `deleted` in your `DELETE` statement. Also, what is `select count(*) from DELETED having count(*)=1` trying to achieve? You don't do anything with that dataset, and returning a dataset in a trigger is deprecated; so you shouldn't be doing it. Also, your `BEGIN` should be before the above mentioned `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I was trying to count the rows from the DELETED table so that the trigger only works when deleting the last product from a productcategory

Comment: But you need to count *by category* and you need to *do something* with that count. Right now you're just saying select having count(*) = 1 which is going to only happen when they've deleted exactly one row. Couldn't they delete 5 rows from 5 different categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this more concisely, but I wrote it this way to separate the selection of (a) categories with more than one row affected in the current delete operation, (b) categories in the table that have more than one product, and then (c) rows to delete based on being part of (a) but *not* part of (b).

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dbo.mytrigger1;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.mytrigger1
ON dbo.Product
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ;WITH SingleRowCategoriesAffected AS 
  (
    -- categories where only one row was deleted
    SELECT product_productcategory_id 
      FROM deleted
      GROUP BY product_productcategory_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  ),
  MultiRowCategoriesLeft AS
  (
     -- categories remaining that have more than one product
     SELECT product_productcategory_id
       FROM Product
       GROUP BY product_productcategory_id
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
  DELETE c
    FROM dbo.Productcategory AS c
    INNER JOIN SingleRowCategoriesAffected AS s
    ON c.productcategory_id = s.product_productcategory_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MultiRowCategoriesLeft AS m
    ON s.product_productcategory_id = m.product_productcategory_id
    WHERE m.product_productcategory_id IS NULL;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all rows from Productcategory, which doesn't has corresponding products and have been deleted within this operation (i.e. exists in deleted pseudo table):

```
    delete from Productcategory 
    where produktcategory_id in (select product_productcategory_id from deleted)
      and not exists(select * from Product where product_productcategory_id = Productcategory.produktcategory_id)
```

Comment: it will also run if more products are deleted at a time

Comment: That makes no sense to me. So if I delete the last product, the categorie is deleted. But if I delete the last product and my delete removes more than one row, the categorie is not deleted ? I just cannot understand this logic, can you elaborate please